# How do I create a class with a set variable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following class::

```
class CloudJob {
  final String documentId;
  final String jobCreatorId;
  final String jobDescription;
  final String jobCreatorFirstName;
  final String jobAddress;
  final String jobType;
  final String jobSubState;
  final String jobState;
  final List? jobImagesList;    /// this needs to be a set

  const CloudJob({
    required this.documentId,
    required this.jobCreatorId,
    required this.jobDescription,
    required this.jobCreatorFirstName,
    required this.jobAddress,
    required this.jobType,
    required this.jobSubState,
    required this.jobState,
    this.jobImagesList,
  });
```

I need to make jobImagesList a "set" because its a list of unique strings.
not sure how to do that though

Comment: how about `final Set? jobImagesList;`

Comment: Have you tried this? `final Set<String> jobImagesList = {};`

Comment: Change to Set. What's the issue here ?

Comment: i luv u guys!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```dart
final Set? jobImagesList;
```